# Control youtube chromeless player via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, actionscript-3

Recently I have made a simple flash application that utilizes a webcam feed and an embedded chromeless youtube player within it. I now need to make custom controls around the player but would like to be able to do that in html/css and control it with js/jquery. While I can find material helping me control the chromeless player directly ( as in solo embedded and not part of another flash app ). My question is that since the chromless player is embedded INSIDE of another flash app ( say test.swf ) can I still access the player in there from js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to use JS functions that call AS functions within the flash app that manipulate the player.